# Error checking in outer constructor in Julia

Tags: julia

I have the following `struct` with two outer constructors

```
struct SingleSpinState <: EPState
    spins::BitArray{1}
end

SingleSpinState(n_sites::Int) = SingleSpinState(rand(Bool, n_sites))
SingleSpinState(n_sites::Int, n_particles::Int) = SingleSpinState(cat(1,trues(n_particles),falses(n_sites - n_particles)))
```

In the second constructor I would like to check that `n_sites` > `n_particles`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/constructors/) essential error checking should go on in inner constructors, yet it seems to me that the above situation will be quite common: the outer constructor uses the inner constructor but its arguments will be constrained in some way.

What is proper way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define multiple inner constructors:

```
julia> struct SingleSpinState
           spins::BitVector

           SingleSpinState(n_sites::Int) = new(bitrand(n_sites))

           function SingleSpinState(n_sites::Int, n_particles::Int)
               if !(n_sites > n_particles)
                   throw(ArgumentError("n_sites must be larger than n_particles"))
               end
               new([trues(n_particles); falses(n_sites-n_particles)])
           end
       end

julia> SingleSpinState(2)
SingleSpinState(Bool[false, true])

julia> SingleSpinState(2, 1)
SingleSpinState(Bool[true, false])

julia> SingleSpinState(2, 3)
ERROR: ArgumentError: n_sites must be larger than n_particles
Stacktrace:
[...]
```